# how do i get fancybox content to load after clicking the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

fancybox content loads while the page is loading too.. I want it so where you could load content only when the link is clicked... right now the content inside the fancybox is loading when you open the page. I think you have to put an event handler but I don't know how.

please watch the video to UNDERSTAND FULLY!
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6MxkBhRC-w

here is my code

```
<body>

<a href="#image_link" title="PutLockerMedia" id="click">watch</a>
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="image_link">
    <div class="imageWrapper">
      <div class="image"> 
    <iframe src="http://www.putlocker.com/embed/E25FA20CE8643E5F" width="600" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#click").fancybox();
    });
</script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are loading an `iframe` as *inline* content so regardless it's visible or not, it still loads in the background.

What you have to do is, instead of targeting the inline selector `#image_link`, target directly to the contents of the `iframe` (the value of its `src` attribute) in your `<a>` tag like :

```
<a href="http://www.putlocker.com/embed/E25FA20CE8643E5F" title="PutLockerMedia" id="click">watch</a>
```

... and that's the only html you need (you can delete the hidden `div`)

Then use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        width: 600,
        height: 360
    });
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6K847/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you finally someone understands me god bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know fancybox, but I know something similiar 'lightbox'. I think they may work in same way.

Not the fancybox loads the content you need, but the iframe loads. Fancybox only show it in some style, I think.

So try to remove src attribut in iframe. And try to show fancybox use API. I may use lightbox to show what I mean.

`$("#click").click(function() {$("iframe").attr("src","xxxx"); $.lightbox("#image_link")})`

I hope it helps.